# Can I statistically compare two indirect effects in a multi-group path analysis where the indirect effects are estimated through bootstrapping?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, bootstrap, mediation

I've conducted a multi-groups path analysis with maximum likelihood estimation and 10,000 bootstrap samples to assess the indirect effect of an exogenous variable on an endogenous variable.

There are two groups in my analysis and I want to statistically compare the indirect effects for the two groups.

The standardized indirect effect for Group 1 is .218 with a bootstrapped standard error of .079.
The standardized indirect effect for Group 2 is .391 with a bootstrapped standard error of .065.

Are these indirect effects significantly different from each other? Is it possible to determine this from the information listed above?

Comment: That depends. For example, if the original data has only three items it wouldn't be at all accurate. On the other hand, if you start with 21 samples, and do model-based bootstrap of normally distributed homoscedastic residuals so that the pool of outcomes is $20^{20}$, then there won't be important repetition in the bootstrapped results, then you can. Why you would want to use standard error for a distribution that may not be normal is what, exactly? So, we could use a few more details here.